# Display powers of Phi with Fibonacci precision

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci

Write some code that takes a single non-negative integer \$n\$ and outputs the \$n\$th power of phi (\$\phi\$, the Golden Ratio, approximately 1.61803398874989) with the same number of decimal digits as the \$n\$th Fibonacci number.

Your code must produce the correct sequence of digits for all inputs up to at least 10 (55 decimal digits). The output must be human-readable decimal. You may choose whether to round the last digit to the closest value, or truncate the value. Please specify which one your code uses.

\$n\$ and output, up to 10, rounding down:

```
 0   1
 1   1.6
 2   2.6
 3   4.23
 4   6.854
 5  11.09016
 6  17.94427190
 7  29.0344418537486
 8  46.978713763747791812296
 9  76.0131556174964248389559523684316960
10 122.9918693812442166512522758901100964746170048893169574174
```

\$n\$ and output, up to 10, rounding to the closest value:

```
 0   1
 1   1.6
 2   2.6
 3   4.24
 4   6.854
 5  11.09017
 6  17.94427191
 7  29.0344418537486
 8  46.978713763747791812296
 9  76.0131556174964248389559523684316960
10 122.9918693812442166512522758901100964746170048893169574174
```

The 7th Fibonacci number is 13, so the output for \$n=7\$, \$\phi^7\$, has 13 decimal places. You must not truncate trailing zeros that would display too few digits; see output for 6 in the first table, which ends in a single zero to keep the decimal precision at 8 digits.

Maybe as a bonus, say what the highest number your program can correctly output is.

Comment: What about languages that can't handle that many decimal places? I got a 24 byte Pyth solution here that only works till n=7, since I can't display more than 15 decimal places. Should I post it anyway?

Comment: @DenkerAffe Sure, you can post it but with a note saying that it's not valid because it can't do the last three test cases. It might be inspiration for someone to add precision to your answer!

Answer (score 4):

## dc, 26 bytes

```
99k5v1+2/?^d5v/.5+0k1/k1/p
```

Due to the initial precision of 99 digits after the comma, this will work up yo input **11**. A dynamic (or higher static) precision is possible, but would elevate the byte count.

#### Test cases

```
$ for ((i = 0; i < 11; i++)) { dc -e '99k5v1+2/?^d5v/.5+0k1/k1/p' <<< $i; }
1
1.6
2.6
4.23
6.854
11.09016
17.94427190
29.0344418537486
46.978713763747791812296
76.0131556174964248389559523684316960
122.9918693812442166512522758901100964746170048893169574174
```

#### How it works

Since the desired output is **φ<sup>n</sup>**, we can calculate the the Fibonacci number **F(n)** as **⌊φ<sup>n</sup> ÷ √5 + 0.5⌋** with little additional effort.

```
99k                         Set the precision to 99.
   5v                       Compute the square root of 5.
     1+                     Add 1.
       2/                   Divide by 2.
                            This pushes the golden ratio.
         ?                  Read the input from STDIN.
          ^                 Elevate the golden ratio to that power.
           d                Push a copy.
            5v/             Divide it by the square root of 5.
               .5+          Add 0.5.
                  0k        Set the precision to 0.
                    1/      Divide by 1, truncating to the desired precision.
                            This pushes F(n).
                      k     Set the precision to F(n).
                       1/   Divide by 1, truncating to the desired precision.
                         p  Print.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 50 bytes

```
N[GoldenRatio^#,2^#]~NumberForm~{2^#,Fibonacci@#}&
```

Basic solution. Rounds to the nearest value. <s>Still verifying the highest value that won't make my computer run out of memory.</s> Input `32` works, but it takes 45 minutes and uses 16GiB of RAM. However, given infinite time and memory, this could theoretically run for any value.

Comment: Would you post the output please? I need to cheat and use your output to add the last few test cases. Which way are you rounding? Down or to nearest? "Infinite resources" is good enough. I don't require that you run out of memory!

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 65 bytes

```
a=>Math.pow((1+Math.sqrt(5))/2,a).toFixed(k(a));k=b=>b?b+k(b-1):0
```

Getting Phi by calculating `(1+Math.sqrt(5))/2`.

Getting Fib value using the function: `k=b=>b?b+k(b-1):0`.

[Try it out](https://tio.run/##bc65EsIgFIXh3ie5TAyGaFyH2Nn5EJCQiMSAwLg8PS6dc@3OfHOK/yxuIjReu5gHp1vlL3Y06pk6ngSvjyKeqLN3AJZ9d7j6CBUhs3IqCI32oB@qBQOCkJ3hktdyLzMDMmdkW6TGjsEOig62hw6K92fySwxTiWmOaYGpwrTEtMK0xrT5k/rJTy8)

Comment: `.5+Math.sqrt(5)/2` removes 1 byte